# Attempted import error: 'alpha' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/styles'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use the material-ui/lab date picker, however I'm getting this error! I have updated my material-ui version using `npm install @material-ui/core@latest` and it worked fine. However, I lost the ability to use `createMuiTheme` & `MuiThemeProvider`.

Comment: Please add the code which is causing the error. Also, MUI's date picker is part of the `@material-ui/pickers` library, not the core one

Comment: mmmm. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/2157 . They are ending the @material-ui/picker as it will be part of the core in V5 Stable release

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @XhLin Yes, @material-ui/picker is no longer supported and will be migrated to the core in V5 Stable release. I just checked and V5 still haven't released. You can use the  @material-ui/pickers library until the V5 release.

Comment: So don't use @material-ui/lab, use @material-ui/pickers instead?

Comment: Yeah you can use till you feel the need to switch to material-ui/lab

Comment: @Ibra If your problem has been resolved, can you post an answer about how did you resolve it and mark it as accept? It can help future people with the same problem!

Answer (score 16):

Maybe it'll be helpful for someone. For me fix of that issue was to change the indirect import to direct one:

so this triggered the error:

```
import { Alert } from '@material-ui/lab';
```

this works fine:

```
import Alert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';
```

Comment: @Khasky I am getting the same problem with Skeleton. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AndreaD_ Updating `@material-ui/core` and `@material-ui/lab` to the latest versions resolved issue for me

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with Skeleton using version @material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.60 but changing it to version @material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.57 fixed it for me ... guess they broke it again :)

Answer (score 6):

You should update your package.json  with following:

```
"@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.57",
"@material-ui/pickers": "3.2.10",
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to downgrade `npm node@11.15.0` and `npm install @material-ui/core@4.12.1` then it fixed all issues. Please check node version with your node.

Answer (score 2):

Please try updating to latest version of `@material-ui/core`. That should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

My material-ui version when first downloaded was an earlier version.
Then i ran:

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

to let it upgrade automatically to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I was using MUI v4 and was trying to use the Appbar from MUI, updating my MUI by running the command `npm install @material-ui/core@latest` and restarting the server by using `npm start` worked for Me, Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

update  `npm @material-ui/cor`e package `npm update` resolved my issue

Answer (score -1):

i can't solve this problem with above solutions.
so manually change 'alpha' to 'fade' in material ui files

> ./node_modules/@material_ui/lab/esm/

for example :

> import { fade, withStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

### instead

> import { alpha, withStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

it's works for me
but it's not correct solutions.